# Is R Reflexive on N and Z

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

In Vellemans book "How to prove it" (4th edition, section 4.3 exercise 24) the following question is posed: "Let R = {(m, n) ∈ N × N: |m − n| ≤ 1}, which is a relation on N. Note that R ⊆ Z × Z, so R is also a relation on Z." **Note: N is the set of natural numbers {0, 1, 2, ...} and Z the set of integers {..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...}.**

He then asks two questions:

1. Is R reflexive on N?
2. Is R reflexive on Z?

I have the following proof for the first question:
Suppose we take some x from N, we want to show that xRx. This means x element of N x N, which is obviously true and also that |x − x| ≤ 1. Because x is positive x - x = 0 and so 0 ≤ 1. But also |0| ≤ 1, because |0| = 0, this shows that |x − x| ≤ 1.

However I'm not 100% sure on how to approach the second question. I assume I have to show that if x element of Z then xRx. I assume the same logic applies for |x − x| ≤ 1 because -x - (-x) = -x + x = 0. However x is not necessarily an element of N, which if I understand correctly is a condition for x to be part of R. As a counterexample (-1, -1) is given but it is not explained why this is a counterexample.

Do I understand correctly it's this first condition, namely (x, x) element of N x N that makes it so that R is not reflexive on Z or am I making a mistake somewhere else?

Comment: Just to clarify, by $\mathbb Z$ you mean the set of integers $\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\dots\}$?  (I was taught that whole numbers means $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.)

Comment: Hello I'm dutch and over here we call them "whole numbers", so I translated it and put it up like this. However it seems in English they are called the integers. I changed the description and included a set expansion to make it a bit more clear. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: This is an exercise is *precision*.  If $R$ were reflexive on $\mathbb Z$ that would mean for every $z\in \mathbb Z$ we'd have $(z,z) \in R$.  We can only have $(x,y) \in R$ if *two* conditions are met.  1)  $x,y \in \mathbb N$.  That *IS* part of the definition and 2) $|x-y| \le 1$.  As $-1 \not \in \mathbb N$ we can not have $(-1,-1) \in R$ because of condition 1.  Condition 2 is ... irrelevant.

Comment: "However x is not necessarily an element of N, which if I understand correctly is a condition for x to be part of R"  !EXACTLY!  If either $w$ or $y$ is not in $\mathbb N$ then $(w,y)\not \in R$ not matter *what* $|w-y|$ is.   "As a counterexample (-1, -1) is given but it is not explained why this is a counterexample."  But you *JUST* explained it.  $-1 \not \in \mathbb N$ so $(-1,-1)\not \in R$ no matter *what* $|(-1)-(-1)|$ is..... Alternatively we can just *look* at $R$ and se it is $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0), (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2).... etc\}$ and *none*of those include any negative integers!

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanations @fleablood. I often doubt myself in discrete maths because precision and applying definitions correctly is crucial. I wanted to be absolutely sure this was the reason why. I'm mostly doing self study so there's not a lot of people I can ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(-1,-1)$ is a counterexample to statement 2 ($R$ reflexive in $\mathbb Z$) as

- $-1 \in \mathbb Z$ and so $(-1,-1) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$
- $-1=-1$
- $(-1,-1) \not \in R$ because $-1 \not \in \mathbb N$ and $(-1,-1)  \not \in \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$

so the answer to 2 is "no, $R$ is not reflexive in $\mathbb Z$".

Comment: Oh I see, I was not sure if that was the problem. That (−1,−1) ∉ N×N instead of the second clause |x − x| ≤ 1. So If R was defined on Z instead it would be true I assume? Just asking out of curiosity, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Yes, if you had had $R = \{(m, n) \in \mathbb Z \times  × \mathbb Z: |m − n| ≤ 1\}$ , then it would have been be reflexive in  $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear for me now.

Comment: If $R' = \{(m,n)\in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z: |m-n| \le 1\}$ then $R'$ *would* be reflexive on $\mathbb Z$.  But note $Z\subset \mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R\subset \mathbb C$ so $R'$ is also a relationship on $\mathbb Q, \mathbb R, \mathbb C$.  But it is not reflexive on any of those as $(w,y)\in \mathbb R$ only if (but not if) $w,y \in \mathbb Z$.  So $(\frac 12, \frac 12), (\pi, \pi), (2+3i, 2+3i)$ not in $R'$, etc.  The second condition need not matter if the *first* condition fails.